# Multiple Threads in Xpages

Tags: multithreading, xpages

I have a problem and hoped somone could help me

I'm trying to start multiple threads from an XAgent (not rendered XPage)

```
public class ImportThread extends NotesThread {

Session currentSession;

public ImportThread(String maildb, String Server)
{

try{
   currentSession =DominoAccess.getCurrentSession();
   this.maildb = currentSession.getDatabase(Server, maildb);
}catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public void runNotes()
{
   View v = maildb.getView("$Calendar");
}
```

in this version I could not access the View I only get "null" back
Ive tryed a version with Java Threads not realy better.

thean i've found something on Openntf 
http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Threads%20and%20Jobs

but there I got an "AccessControl Exception"

I have no more ideas, I hope that someone has an idea how to create 
an XAgent with multiple thread

Comment: Did you enable security permissions as mentioned in Thread and Jobs documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Egor wrote you need the change the Java policy file if you run the Java code from an NSF. You don't have to do this if you deploy your Java code as OSGi plugin. See the documentation of that OpenNTF project.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik NotesObjects should not be shared between threads. So instead of using Database mailDB you should use String mailDBName and instantiate all NotesObjects inside their own thread. You also need to watch run time: if your XAgent waits for the treads to conclude, you should be fine, but if it is a 'fire-and-forget' approach you need to start it from something more persistent like a managed bean in the session scope.
Hope that helps